# Angular change detection not triggered for descendents with OnPush strategy

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I'm using an angular directive on form components that when they're submitted, their form group and all their inputs are marked as touched. Here is the component:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'form[formGroup]',
})
export class MarkAllAsTouchedDirective {
  @HostListener('submit')
  onSubmit(): void {
    this.container.control?.markAllAsTouched();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  constructor(
    @Self() private container: ControlContainer,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}
}
```

Now in my application, I'm nesting a component with a change detection strategy of `OnPush` inside my form component. Almost like below:

```
<form
  [formGroup]="someForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
>
  <app-account-form
    [someForm]="someForm"
  ></app-account-form>

  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

And the `app-account-form` component which has `OnPush` strategy is as follows:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-form',
  templateUrl: './account-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-form.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AccountFormComponent {
  @Input() someForm!: FormGroup;
}
```

My problem is that the `app-account-form` component does not detect changes made to the `someForm` form group even though I'm calling the `detectChanges` method inside the `MarkAllAsTouchedDirective` directive above.

What is the problem here? Am I misunderstanding the implementation of `detectChanges` and if it is applying to all the descendants?

Answer (score 2):

ChangeDetectorReference.detectChanges() triggers CD on a component and its children by respecting the CD strategy of the children. As the `AccountFormComponent` has OnPush strategy, it would only be marked for changes if the `someForm` input changed. To determine if the input changed, Angular does a simple `===` comparison, it is not a deep object comparison. In your case, even though the touch property of the `someForm` object changed, the reference is still the same, so the `AccountFormComponent` will not be marked to be checked.

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/885f1af509eb7d9ee049349a2fe5565282fbfefb/packages/core/src/util/comparison.ts#L13) is the code in Angular that does the comparison, quoted from [this great article about Change Detection](https://mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/#how-change-detection-works).

To gain more insights about CD:

The [Angular DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh) provide a profiler that lists all change detection events, shows the source for each event and also allows you to see which component has been checked during each CD cycle. Just make sure to select the "flame graph" and tick the "Show only change detection" checkbox. The components marked blue have been checked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are mentioning that `detectChanges` triggers CD on a component and **its children**. So what is the difference between when `detectChanges` is called on a component that is an ancestor of `component A`, and when it is called on `component A` itself that has `OnPush` strategy? Because in the second example everything works fine.

Comment: Thank you for checking back on this. I was not precise in my answer and just updated it: by calling `detectChanges`, the component where the call is executed will be checked for changes, even if it is uses the OnPush strategy and the "normal" criteria to mark it to be checked are not met. But for all children, the OnPush strategy will be respected as usual. This explains why `component A` is checked for changes, if the `detectChanges` call is done inside it, but not if it is done in the parent.